# Two Dataset without joining them in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have two Datasets in my SSRS report and both dataset coming from different database. and there impossible to join them

Example not real Data .....
so what im tring to do is (Dataset1) total number of Visiter  divided by (Dataset2) Total number of Cars * 1000 (sectors) row group by every month and Year.

for example (not real) if we have 24 Visitors and 2063 Cars *1000 so we get AVG of 1000 Sectors 11.63

Is there any funcation in SSRS where i solve this problem IN Excel you know i easy but I need to create report in SSRS please any help would safe me.  Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtbfZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

The lookup function in SSRS allows you to get fields from a different dataset based on matching criteria.

See here for more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ee210531.aspx

Comment: AS i said there is no primary key and forgein key where i JOin them

Comment: Are you able to join on two or more common fields that can combine to make a unique key? For example you can do `lookup(Fields!Year.Value & "|" & Fields!DayofYear.Value & "|" & Fields!Type.Value` to create a unique key based on year, day and type.  Alternatively, you can aggregate fields from within another dataset - `sum(Fields!CarNumber.Value, "DS1")` or you look at doing custom code to do an aggregate function on a lookupset.

Comment: there is no common fileds in both dataset

Comment: @Skorpion You mentioned a method in Excel to achieve this - what would you do? Maybe we can help based on that.

Comment: i just added the pic

Comment: You can use either `sum(Fields!CarNumber.Value, "DS1")` to sum a numeric field, or `count(Fields!CarNumber.Value, "DS1")` to count the items in the dataset if this is more appropriate.

Comment: im using this exp =count(Fields!Month.Value,"Ds_Passenger")/Sum(Fields!TOTALFLIGHT.Value,"DS_Cars") group by Month and Year and getting error the ex used for the calculated filed ... includes an aggregate,rownumber,Ruuning valuse,Previousor lookup.aggregate,rownumber,Ruuning valuse,Previousor lookup funcation cannot be used in calculated field expressions,

Comment: I fixed the prblem includes an aggregate,rownumber,Ruuning valuse,Previousor lookup.aggregate,row number,Ruuning value,Previous lookup function cannot be used in calculated field expressions,

Now i want Group by Mnth and Year (Dataset1)

Comment: @Skorpion if you have month and year in each dataset, then a lookup/lookupset will work for you. If you don't have them in each dataset then you cannot do what you want.